# Cannot open the destfile when I download the data from the internet using the R function download.file

Tags: r, r-raster

I tried to download the file from the internet, but the downloaded file (raster format) cannot load.

```
# download the data
download.file("https://zenodo.org/record/4287825/files/ChinaClim_baseline_prec_01.tif?download=1", destfile="prec_01.tif")
# load into Raster
library(raster)
raster("prec_01.tif")
# Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
# Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

Anything wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Your code works well on my machine, what is your `packageVersion("raster")` ?

Comment: On windows add `mode = "wb"` to `download.file()`, as explained on the help page `?download.file`.

Answer (score 1):

```
download.file("https://zenodo.org/record/4287825/files/ChinaClim_baseline_prec_01.tif?download=1", destfile="prec_01.tif", mode="wb") # On windows add mode = "wb" to download.file() as suggested by Martin Morgan
# load into Raster
library(raster)
raster("prec_01.tif")
```